# Algorithm for predict(start=start_date, end=end_date) on unique same named weather station

Tags: python

**Problem on Algorithm for same like 'stations'**

Problem is to use weather data to run ARIMA model fit on each group of like named 'stations' with their associated precipitation data, then finally execute a 30 day forward forecast. Looking to process specific same named stations and then next process the next unique same named stations, etc.

**The algorithm to add question**

How to re-write algorithm to run ARIMA model for each UNIQUE 'station' and, perhaps grouping stations to be unique groups to run ARIMA model on the group, and then fit for a 30 day forward forecast? The ARIMA(2,1,1) is a working order terms from auto.arima().

How to re-write a group algorithm for same named 'stations' before running the ARIMA model, fit, forecast? Or what other approach would achieve a set of like named stations to process specific same named stations and then move unto the next unique same named stations.

**Working code executes but needs broader algorithm**
Code was working, but on last run, predict(start=start_date, end=end_date) issued a key error. Removed NA, so this may fix the predict(start, end)

```
wd.weather_data = wd.weather_data[wd.weather_data['date'].notna()]

forecast_models = [50000]
n = 1
df_all_stations = data_prcp.drop(['level_0', 'index', 'prcp'], axis=1)

wd.weather_data.sort_values("date", axis = 0, ascending = True, inplace = True)

for station_name in wd.weather_data['station']:
  start_date = pd.to_datetime(wd.weather_data['date'])
  number_of_days = 31
  end_date = pd.to_datetime(start_date) + pd.DateOffset(days=30)
  model = statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA(wd.weather_data['prcp'], order=(2,1,1))
  model_fit = model.fit()
  forecast = model_fit.predict(start=start_date, end=end_date)
  forecast_models.append(forecast)
```

**Data Source**

<bound method NDFrame.head of                  station       date       tavg       tmin   tmax  prcp  snow  
0           Anchorage, AK 2018-01-01  -4.166667  -8.033333  -0.30   0.3  80.0
35328     Grand Forks, ND 2018-01-01 -14.900000 -23.300000  -6.70   0.0   0.0
86016        Key West, FL 2018-01-01  20.700000  16.100000  25.60   0.0   0.0
59904      Wilmington, NC 2018-01-01  -2.500000  -7.100000   0.00   0.0   0.0
66048   State College, PA 2018-01-01 -13.500000 -17.000000 -10.00   4.5   0.0
...                   ...        ...        ...        ...    ...   ...   ...
151850    Kansas City, MO 2022-03-30   9.550000   3.700000  16.55  21.1   0.0
151889    Springfield, MO 2022-03-30  12.400000   4.500000  17.10  48.9   0.0
151890      St. Louis, MO 2022-03-30  14.800000   8.000000  17.60  24.9   0.0
151891  State College, PA 2022-03-30   0.400000  -5.200000   6.20   0.2   0.0
151899     Wilmington, NC 2022-03-30  14.400000   6.200000  20.20   0.0   0.0

```
     wdir       wspd         pres
```

0       143.0   5.766667   995.133333
35328   172.0  33.800000  1019.200000
86016     4.0  13.000000  1019.900000
59904   200.0  21.600000  1017.000000
66048   243.0  12.700000  1015.200000
...       ...        ...          ...
151850  294.5  24.400000   998.000000
151889  227.0  19.700000   997.000000
151890  204.0  20.300000   996.400000
151891  129.0  10.800000  1020.400000
151899  154.0  16.400000  1021.900000

**Error**

```
KeyError: 'The `start` argument could not be matched to a location related to the index of the data.'
```

Comment: We cannot answer _How to re-write algorithm_ or fix your `KeyError`, so this is off-topic.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because CodeReview@SE is about insights about code working as intended. `needs broader algorithm` is off-topic.